# Is there a way to improve the performance of this draggable world map?

Tags: javascript, webkit, maps, draggable

I implemented a simple draggable world map for a game but the performance differs when using different browsers - which is kinda obvious. I used 256x256 pixle tiles and the script dynamically renders the number to fill the whole window plus borders.

Prototype: http://mt111102.students.fhstp.ac.at/draggable/game.html

Currently I'm doing it simply by setting the `top` and `left` style attributes on mousemove. Heres a snippet:

```
mouseDown : function(e) {
    Map.myPreventDefault(e);

    dx = map.offsetLeft - e.clientX;
    dy = map.offsetTop - e.clientY;

    map.addEventListener('mousemove', Map.divMove, false);
},

divMove : function(e) {
    Map.myPreventDefault(e);

    map.style.position = "absolute";
    map.style.cursor = "move";

    map.style.left = e.clientX + dx + "px";
    map.style.top = e.clientY + dy + "px";
}
```

Later when dragging to the borders I'm gonna load new tiles with XHR and delete old ones on the other end to retain performance so that the wrapper doesn't get to big.

My question is: Would it be more performant by using CSS translate instead of just setting the `top` and `left` attributes? And do you guys have **any** tips how to make it smoother?

In Firefox the prototype works almost perfectly smooth but in Webkit browsers like Chrome it doesn't look very good - it lags a bit. I just wonder how Google Maps managed it to work in every modern browser with the same smoothness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS transform, especially with a Z value (which will load the transform into the GPU), will almost always be faster and smoother - especially on devices like iPads, but elsewhere as well.

For more details you can check out this tutorial on GPU acceleration:

- http://creativejs.com/2011/12/day-2-gpu-accelerate-your-dom-elements/